# Quantum Info in math departments

Tags: soft-question, physics, mathematical-physics, quantum-mechanics, quantum-information

I'm currently a graduate student in mathematics getting my master's degree. I am interested in a bit probability and partial differential equations, and, secondarily, a bit of mathematical physics; most likely quantum information theory. I'll most likely be moving to a different graduate program after completing my master's degree from my current institution , and I'm currently trying to figure out whether there are mathematics departments that have research groups in quantum information theory. I believe I will want to stay in a mathematics department, as I'm not awfully interested in the experimental aspects of quantum information. I'm more interested in the mathematical aspects of the subject, and I'll definitely be applying with the approach where I'll try and cash on my undergraduate background in physics/quantum mechanics, and use my knowledge of math in topology, functional analysis, real analysis etc. to put it to good, meaningful use to solve inter-disciplinary problems.

However, I'm not sure whether there are a large number of math departments in the US that have research groups in quantum information? I know there's one at UC Davis,

http://qmap.ucdavis.edu/,

and I think the math department at UT Austin collaborates heavily with the physics/cs departments, so I won't be surprised if they have people working in quantum information over there.

I'm not, however, sure whether these departments/research groups are anomalies. It'd be great if someone could nudge me in the right answer to this direction? List of math departments doing quantum information? Or should I look at CS/Physics departments*?

*I don't think I will apply to physics schools because I am not really interested in the experimental aspects, and I don't think I can sum up the courage to take both the math/physics GRE this year, for which I will have to study from the scratch.

Comment: caltech has a top tier department, http://iqim.caltech.edu/portfolio_category/quantum-information/

Comment: @Thoth: Thanks for the suggestion. Any other suggestions, though? Getting into Caltech is quite difficult for almost anyone, even the best of students.

Comment: http://www.qit.ethz.ch, not in the US

Comment: Also, I wouldn't focus too much on what department the group is in, if you know for sure you want to do QIT, then you should be focusing on individual professors whose research best aligns with your interests.

Comment: Also also, Scott Aaronson is at UT Austin, he has a blog that might interest you, he's a heavy weight in quantum computational complexity theory, if that flavor of QIT interests you.

Comment: @Thoth Yes, I'm aware Scott Aaronson is at UT Austin, and I'm definitely going to apply to UT Austin. But then again, he's in a CS department, which leads me back to my original question, given my hierarchy of primary and secondary interests, should I be considering/targeting math programs or cs/stats programs. Physics seems far fetched; taking the physics gre along with the math gre would be a daunting challenge.

Comment: Not in the US, but [University of Waterloo](https://uwaterloo.ca/math/) (in Canada) is a great place for mathematics of quantum information theory

Comment: @luftbahnfahrer Yes, it's definitely going to be on my radar. May be a long shot, but I'll take a go at it.